# PHP MySQL select random rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem selecting 6 random friends

This is the query I've got so far:

```
$result = num_rows("SELECT * FROM friends WHERE member_id = '".$_SESSION['userid']."'");
if($result >= 6) {
    $f_num = 6;
} else {
    $f_num = $result;
}
for($i = 1; $i <= $f_num; $i++) {
    $q_get_member_friends = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM friends WHERE member_id = '".$_SESSION['userid']."' ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1");
    $r_get_member_friends = mysql_fetch_array($q_get_member_friends);
    echo $r_get_member_friends['friend_with'];
}
```

I want to select 6 random friends if the logged in user has more or equal to 6 friends

Stuck on this for a while now :/

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Only if the person has 6 or more friends?

Comment: A bit off topic but you can save time by using braces in strings. Like instead of `'".$_SESSION['userid']."'"` You can use ` '{$_SESSION['userid']}'"`

Comment: only if the person has 6 or more, yes
good to know :)

Comment: @Shubham If it's only a one-dimensional array, it's even enough to write `"'$_SESSION[userid]'"`. :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you use:

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM friends 
   WHERE member_id = '".$_SESSION['userid']."' 
ORDER BY rand() 
   LIMIT 6
```

If the person only has 3 friends, the query will only show those three - it doesn't mean that the query will always return six rows.

Comment: Order by rand is dangerously slow with lots of data.

Comment: There's an article here with details and alternatives: http://www.titov.net/2005/09/21/do-not-use-order-by-rand-or-how-to-get-random-rows-from-table/

Answer (score 5):

The best way I've found to select any number of random records is with OFFSET in the query.

Let's say you want 6 random records, so I'll borrow from an answer above and count the total number of friends in the database.

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM friends WHERE member_id='". $_SESSION['userid'] ."'");

$get_count = mysql_fetch_array($sql); // Fetch the results

$numfriends = $get_count['total']; // We've gotten the total number
```

Now we'll get the 6 random records out of the total above (hopefully it's > 6),

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM friends WHERE member_id='". $_SESSION['userid'] ."' LIMIT 6 OFFSET " . (rand(0, $numFriends));


while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
  /// show your $rows here
}
```

Using OFFSET may not be the best or most efficient, but it's worked for me on large databases without bogging them down.

Comment: It may not have any record after some rows if you use offset as random. I think thats better to get the results as array and then we can use shuffle method to mix the elements of the array. In order to get first 6 elements, we can use array_slice($array, 0, 6);

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I figured it out :)
Had to use **while** not **for** :'D

Answer (score 0):

First select the number of friends that the user has:

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) as numFriends FROM friends WHERE member_id='".$_SESSION['userid']."'
```

...put that into a variable, let's call it "$numFriends"
Then:

```
for($z=0;$z<6;$z++)
{
   $randomFriendIndex = rand(1,$numFriends);
   //Get the friend at that index
}
```

Comment: do I have to use that query in a num_rows or fetch_array?

Answer (score 0):

change `limit 1` to `limit 6` on the eighth line.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `SELECT *` at the beginning, try `SELECT COUNT(*)` and use the actual return value instead of num_rows().

Your loop could generate duplicates. I would suggest trying OMG Ponies answer.

There is a whole chapter about random selection in the book [SQL Antipatterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356557).