# How do I randomly select 6 different images from a folder which is uploaded to a database?

Tags: php, html

Right now, I am doing a project where I have an image gallery and I want to take out 6 different pictures at random. The images are uploaded to database from which I drag them out with a RAND(). But right now they all select the same image.

```
<?php 

    include('dbconfig.php');
    $db = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','eksamen');

    $sql    = "SELECT *
              FROM images
              ORDER BY RAND()
              LIMIT 1
              ";

    foreach($db->query($sql) as $row){
        // $row['id'];
}         





?>
```

```
<div id="gallery">
                <h1>Billedgalleri</h1>

                <div class="gallery_wrapper">

                    <img src="Img/gallery/<?php echo $row['imagename'] ?>" height="90px;"   width="90px;">
                    <img src="Img/gallery/<?php echo $row['imagename'] ?>" height="90px" width="90px;">
                    <img src="Img/gallery/<?php echo $row['imagename'] ?>" width="90px;" height="90px;">

                </div>

                <div class="gallery_wrapper">

                    <img src="Img/gallery/<?php echo $row['imagename'] ?>" width="90px;" height="90px;">
                    <img src="Img/gallery/<?php echo $row['imagename'] ?>" height="90px;" width="90px;">
                    <img src="Img/gallery/<?php echo $row['imagename'] ?>" height="90px;" width="90px;">

                </div>

            </div>
```

> this is the page where I create the image uploads. hope this helps

```
    <?php

        include('dbconfig.php');
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            $name = $_POST['name'];
            $img  = $_FILES['image']['name'];

            $insert = "insert into images values ('NULL','$name','$img')";
            $db     = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','eksamen');
            if(mysqli_query($db,$insert)){
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], "Img/gallery/$img");
                echo "<script>alert('Image has been uploaded')</script>";
            }else{
                echo "<script>alert('Image has failed to upload')</script>";
            }
        }
     ?>


    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Admin</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="admin.css">
    </head>
    <body>

        <form action="admin.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
            <input type="file" id="image_name" name="image">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="upload The Picture">



        <!--    <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Upload the picture">Upload File</button> -->

        </form> 

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: `LIMIT 6` maybe?

Comment: `RAND()` has a possiblity of duplicates @AbraCadaver

Comment: Can you show the `SHOW CREATE TABLE image` output and edit the question with that information?

Comment: i have added the code i use to upload images. i hope that was what you want to know.

Abra, i have already tried putting it to 6 but that just takes 6 "different" images in the same picture box

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP MySQL select random rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340061/php-mysql-select-random-rows)

Comment: Nik, the guy you linked had an answer where he wrote " WHERE member_id = '".$_SESSION['userid']."' ", would my solution be to write $_SESSION['imagename'] to find images instead? obviously changing the member_id

Comment: You're fetching only 1 row from `images` table. As @AbraCadaver said, try `LIMIT 6` instead of `LIMIT 1`. Then print out the results.

Comment: Already tried that. it does not show 6 different images in the html. It just show 6 of the same images in 1 box, and does the same for all other 6

Comment: If you want to upload multiple files at once, make your file input field like this: `<input type="file" id="image_name" name="image[]" multiple>`. Don't forget, it's an array of files. Then, handle your uploaded files in PHP like this: `$_FILES['image']['name'][]`.

Comment: It's not that i want to upload multiple files, i want to drag out multiple different files by random with the html code in the gallery. So i have 6 different pictures which i want all of them to select a random picture by themselves. Right now in my code they all select the same image randomly